# stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: is producing an odd result

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

So I have two arrays:

One is holding HTML reserved characters. The other is  holding the entities to replace them with. I am placing both the arrays in a dictionary

I am then iterating through the dictionary and trying to replace all the occurences of the HTML reserved characters with the appropriate entities.

```
NSArray * chars = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"&", @"\"", nil];
NSArray * entities = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"&amp;", @"&quot;", nil];
NSDictionary * dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:entities forKeys: chars];  

NSArray * keys;
NSUInteger i, count;
id key, value;

keys = [dict allKeys];
count = [keys count];

for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    key = [keys objectAtIndex:i];
    value = [dict objectForKey: key];

    _inputTextView.string = [_inputTextView.string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:key withString:value];
}
```

**The issue I am having**

When the string is a " double quote it prints out &quot; instead of "

Why would this happen?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what is expected to happen. It also seems that it's what you want. The method just replaced the `"` character by its HTML entity counterpart, `&quot;`.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you told your app to replace

> \"

meaning a single double quote without the backslash with

> &quot

and a semicolon. Your App does everything you told it to do. What did you want to do ? Maybe we can help you.

Comment: Well actually the problem is this: 

As the for loop iterates through the string the &amp; is actually replacing all of the ampersands that are prepended to every HTML entity. So instead of the output being &quot; its actually &amp;quot;

Comment: I fixed it!!!!!!

the problem was I was replacing the string "&" with "&amp;" 

I replaced the character string to " & " so it replaces only ampersands on their own and not ones attached to entities..

Thanks guys :)

Comment: OK. I got your point. But unfortunately I'm getting a different result. I've directly copied the code above into xcode and gave the app this string for testing: 

&\" & abc \"

The output was as I expected:

&amp;&quot; &amp; abc &quot; 

Could you please give me your string that is not working ?

Comment: Well the above code was actually a bit masked so I didn't reveal the inner workings of an app im creating. I just tried to simulate the problem. But accidentally ended up posting a working example lol silly of me.